# svm's margin equation derive question

Tags: svm, marginal-distribution

[image]

I hava question about the margin equation 
$$\frac{a}{||w||}$$

where this equation coming from?
I think it substract the $w^{T} +b -a - w^{T}x +b$ but not sure how margin equation derived

Answer (score 0):

That is distance between two parallel hyperplanes: i.e. distance between $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b=c_1$ and $\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}+b=c_2$. The normal (perpendicular) vector for these hyperplanes is $\mathbf{w}$ by definition. And, the distance is measured with $\frac{|c_1-c_2|}{||\mathbf{w}||}$, check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484272/distance-between-two-hyperplanes). In your case $c_1=a,c_2=0$ or $c1=0,c_2=-a$. A simpler situation is lines in 2D, or planes in 3D, which can be found (with its proof) in this wiki [entry](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Distance_between_two_straight_lines#/Formula_and_proof).